# Partial failure of hair dynamics

Tags: hair

The same particle system, part of my hair particle dynamics failed, can someone tell me why?

[image]

I used the default dynamics settings, and part of it worked.
I create a simple scene to recreate, can bake dynamics.

Is this a bug in my file? What is the reason? I used Blender 3.5.0

Comment: Please be more descriptive with your question.  Also, it would help if you upload your .blend. [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com)